# C# using multi-dimensioned array as a property

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace CardV5
{
    class Tee
    {
        private static int numOne = 4;
        private static int numTwo = 2;
        private static int numThree = 22;
        public int Value { get; set; }
        private int[, ,] m_tData = new int[numOne, numTwo, numThree];
        public int TeeData(int IndexOne, int IndexTwo, int IndexThree) 
        { 
            get{return m_tData[IndexOne, IndexTwo, IndexThree];}
            set{m_tData[IndexOne, IndexTwo, IndexThree] = Value;}
        }
    }
}
```

Get and set are red-lined.
Error flag:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

How to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

You've got a regular method there: `public int TeeData(int IndexOne, int IndexTwo, int IndexThree)`. The `get` and `set` notation are for properties, not methods.

I think what you want is an indexed property - just change the parens to square brackets, and you'll use `this` instead of the name:

```
public int this[int IndexOne, int IndexTwo, int IndexThree]
{ 
    get{return m_tData[IndexOne, IndexTwo, IndexThree];}
    set{m_tData[IndexOne, IndexTwo, IndexThree] = Value;}
}
```

This will allow you to do:

```
Tee tee = new Tee();
tee[0,0,0] = /*something*/;
```

Answer (score 1):

get and set apply to properties. In your case you've defined a method. Get\Set is not valid in this context

Answer (score 0):

You could create separate get/set properties:

```
    public int GetTeeData(int IndexOne, int IndexTwo, int IndexThree) 
    { 
        return m_tData[IndexOne, IndexTwo, IndexThree];
    }
    public void GetTeeData(int IndexOne, int IndexTwo, int IndexThree, int value) 
    { 
        m_tData[IndexOne, IndexTwo, IndexThree] = value;
    }
```

or make it an indexer:

```
    public int this[int IndexOne, int IndexTwo, int IndexThree] 
    { 
        get{return m_tData[IndexOne, IndexTwo, IndexThree];}
        set{m_tData[IndexOne, IndexTwo, IndexThree] = Value;}
    }
```